# Show that satisfy the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let be $f(x)$ a function defined for all real numbers. Suppose that $\cos(x)$ is solution to the ODE: $y'=f(y)$. Show that $-\sin(x)$ also is a solution.

I tried using the fact that is a separable ODE, then I have

$$\int_{x_0}^{\cos(x)} \frac{ds}{f(s)} = x + c_1$$ that implies

$$\int_{\cos(x_0)}^{x} \frac{-\sin(s)}{f(\cos(s))} = x + c_1$$ and If I show that $$\int \frac{-\cos(x)}{f(-\sin(x))} = x + c_1$$ then I show that $-\sin(x)$ is a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: What does sen mean?

Comment: @Paul Sorry, is sin(x)

Comment: What is the differential in  the second equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could observe that 
$$-\sin(x) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)$$
and that if 
$$y(x) = \cos(x)$$
then $y'(x) =-\sin(x) = f(\cos(x))$
and so we can say that
$$y(x+\pi/2) = \cos(x+\pi/2)$$
which implies that 
$$y'(x+\pi/2) =-\sin(x+\pi/2) = f(\cos(x+\pi/2)).$$