# Show $-\sin(x)$ is a solution to the same ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Let $\psi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be any function. Suppose $\cos(x)$ is a solution to the ODE $y'=\psi(y)$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Show $-\sin(x)$ is a solution to the same ODE.

Attempt: It is true that $-\sin(x)=\cos(x+\pi/2)$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore,

$$\frac{d}{dx}(-\sin(x))=\cos'(x+\pi/2)=\psi(\cos(x+\pi/2))=\psi(-\sin(x)).$$

Since $\frac{d}{dx}(-\sin(x))=\psi(-\sin(x))$, $-\sin(x)$ must be a solution to the same ODE.

There is an answer for this question at [Show that satisfy the ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3159932/show-that-satisfy-the-ode). I'm wondering if my solution is 1. correct and 2. equivalent to the previous answer. The previous answer was:

You could observe that
$$-\sin(x) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+x\right)$$
and that if
$$y(x) = \cos(x)$$
then $y'(x) =-\sin(x) = f(\cos(x))$
and so we can say that
$$y(x+\pi/2) = \cos(x+\pi/2)$$
which implies that
$$y'(x+\pi/2) =-\sin(x+\pi/2) = f(\cos(x+\pi/2)).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this appears to be the same argument. Generally, for an autonomous ODE $x'=f(x)$, if you have a solution $x$, then also any time-shifted function $x_c(t)=x(t-c)$ is a solution, with the proof following the same steps that you showed.